# how to improve $(call $(eval $(call))) paradigm in using Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I write general makefiles and functions for users' convenience, so naturally they should have the simplest interfaces possible . When defining functions, I use this paradigm:

```
define FUNCTION
target: $1
endef

FUNCTION2 = $(eval $(call FUNCTION,$1))
```

Now, instead of telling them to do this

`$(eval $(call FUNCTION,`argument`))`

I can tell them to do this

`$(call FUNCTION2,`argument`)`

which is simpler.

This worked like a charm until somebody decided to use `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`, so that we have the total code (SSCCE) look like this:

```
define FUNCTION
target: $1
endef

FUNCTION2 = $(eval $(call FUNCTION,$1))

.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:

all:    
    echo OK
```

Now when you `make` this, you get:

```
Makefile:5: *** prerequisites cannot be defined in recipes.  Stop.
```

Well, I guess this is because the recipe `echo` subprocess evaluates the "variable" `FUNCTION2`, which then unexpectedly puts the prerequisite line into the recipe. Or something like that.

So my question is, who is to blame?

Is my paradigm faulty and I should not be using it, because the users then cannot use `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` ? If so, is there a way to fix things, so that users can still call the simple `FUNCTION2`?

Or is `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` an evil feature and should not be used?

Comment: My personal opinion is that `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is an evil feature and should not be used.  However, i think this is worth an enhancement request for GNU make: it shouldn't be running `eval` when expanding variables for export.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you! I was just hoping you would provide your opinion. If you make this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @MadScientist OK I just filed an enhancement request. Thank you again!

Comment: Just as a sidenote, did you already come across [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt)?

Comment: As a minor note: it's not merely about `eval`, it's an expansion issue. Say, if you have `var=$(info Hello)`, then it will print 'Hello' on the screen before executing every recipe.

Comment: @Matt ah yes, thank you Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is that `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is an evil feature and should not be used. However, i think this is worth an enhancement request for GNU make: it shouldn't be running `eval` when expanding variables for export.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unexport FUNCTION FUNCTION2` to get rid of this error.

Yet I have to agree with @MadScientist that `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is evil.

It forcefully performs expansion of **all recursive variables** before executing **every recipe**, so it could easily break any complicated build system.

IMO, it could be useful to have a way to stop **any expansion** of auto-exported variables.

The only consolation is that almost no one uses that `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` thing.

Comment: I suppose that if you enable `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` it's not necessary to expand variables at all before they're put into the environment, because all variables referenced by recursive variable values will also be put into the environment and so will be available in the sub-make.  I guess that's something to consider.  I'd really prefer to just take out that feature but...

Comment: @MadScientist It should work painlessly with (sub)make. But not with shell.

Comment: True.  I guess it depends on why you're exporting.  I'm not really sure how (or if?) there's more we can do other than to disable `eval` which is egregiously wrong.  I thinks `shell` is also disabled to avoid recursion.  But what about other functions?  Maybe make would have to consider them on a case-by-base basis: things like `error` and `info` might not be evaluated, but `notdir` etc. would be, etc.  *sigh*

Comment: @MadScientist In fact, I was thinking about a command-line option. Sort of `-X` to export all; `-x` to export all unexpanded; and if needed it can be changed in makefile by altering `MAKEFLAGS`. Let the user be responsible for all errors that might occur.

Comment: @MadScientist  oh the reason why "they" are exporting everything, is of course because of convenience (at the expense of good design, of course) - they want to make everything "global", in the presence of recursive Make. You define a variable once, you want to have it visible everywhere (downstream). But I have to accomodate that - as a build person, I am supposed to handle everything the developers throw at me and want, not for me to judge whether it may be dumb or not.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Then it's you who have to code defensively and write a ton of `unexport`s to hide all the internals from the outer world. It sucks, but it's quite common. But speaking of a good design, full export would be a good decision for a tool with a different design (thinking of `mk`): if make would operate on the same set of variables and in the same way as shell (same syntax, no recursion, etc.), then there would be no reason to preprocess recipes. No more stupid `$$` and so on. But the price is that there would be no funny eval stuff anymore.

Answer (score -1):

In my non-recursive build system [prorab](https://github.com/cppfw/prorab) I use `eval`, but without `call`.

I pass parameters through `this_`-prefixed variables, something like this:

```
include prorab.mk

this_name := myapp

this_cxxflags += -Wall
this_cxxflags += -DDEBUG
this_cflags += -Wall

this_ldlibs += -lpthread

this_srcs += main.cpp myapp.cpp legacy.c

$(eval $(prorab-build-app))
```

So, `eval` is still there, but inserting variable instead of `call` makes it shorter and also user does not have to remember which argument of the `call` means what, because `this_` variables have descriptive names.

Comment: I don't understand your answer...  it looks like you have not read my question...  If I do what you suggest, the same problem still happens, I checked. Probably because your answer appears to have nothing to do whatsoever with my question, I am sorry to say.

Comment: @MarkGaleck from your question I understood that problem with `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` arises only after you hide `eval` from the user inside of `FUNCTION2`, so I suggested another approach without hiding the `eval` but more user friendly than `$(eval $(call ..., ..., ..., ...))`. But turns out the problem arises not because of this.