# Protecting shell special chars in makefile variable

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh, quoting

I have this:

```
$ cat Makefile
run:
    echo "${var}"
```

When I invoke it like this, I get incorrect result for the second case below:

First case

```
$ make run var='hah(617'
echo "hah(617"
hah(617 #correct
```

Second case

```
$ make run var='hah$^hj'
echo "hahhj" 
hahhj # incorrect, should be hah$^hj
```

How do I fix the Makefile ?

Comment: As a workaround you can replace $ with \$$; make run var='hah\$$^hj'
Unfortunately that doesn't explain why make behaves so unintuitively, nor does it help solving it in the makefile itself

Comment: Yeah I'd like to solve this in Makefile

Comment: `why make behaves so unintuitively` Consider that make has both "simple" and "recursive" variables, unlike shell which only knows "simple" ones. Therefore, you can't easily [export all make variables into the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467690/how-to-improve-call-eval-call-paradigm-in-using-make). Therefore, while writing a recipe, you **must** have some way to differ between make's variables (`CC`, `CFLAGS` etc.) and shell/environment variables.